# Term that describes an incomplete comparison

Tags: phrases

What is the term for a dichotomous statement like, "The two side of the issue are the fish should be protected, or it should not."  That is, the other side of the issue is not fully explained, it's just alluded to by reference to the first side.

Answer (score 1):

As a rhetorical device, this kind of construction is usually referred to as [ellipsis](http://grammar.about.com/od/e/g/ellipsisterm.htm):

> In grammar and rhetoric, ellipsis is the omission of one or more words, which must be supplied by the listener or reader. Adjective: elliptical or elliptic. Plural, ellipses. Also known as an elliptical expression or elliptical clause.

Admittedly, this is a technical term that is likely to be confused with the more common dots (`...`), which are also "ellipses".

Comment: Thanks brianpck.  Is there a, um... less technical term?  Like one that a fourth grader would understand?